# Android getting info from a server through a socket

Tags: android

I have access to a server that streams info to when asked to(like telnet command in Linux), how would I be able access the data from an android, I've searched around and couldn't find guides.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to use a Java [Socket](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html) to pick up the data stream.